# Why is Yahoo blocking our email address verifications and bouncing them back

Tags: email-bounces, verification, spam-marked

I have a legitimate site www.angelescity.ph a Free Classifieds site, once someone posts an advert a verification email is sent.. Yahoo has been blocking them, not delivering and bouncing them back, they also are not answering our enquiries. They are also blocking new subscribers to the site, therefor they cannot place advertisements without an account. Any suggestions?

Comment: If they're bouncing them back then what do the bounce messages say. Have you reviewed the help at the yahoo postmaster tools? Any help we can offer is only going to be along the lines of "follow their best practices and keep trying to speak to them." At the end of the day, it's yahoo's mail system so they make their own rules. http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/postmaster/ http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/postmaster/basics/postmaster-15.html

Comment: could be the country code or your email provider, yahoo gets hit with a lot of spammers, so they are a bit heavy handed with blocking.

Answer (score 3):

What domain are you using to send the email? Does it have a reverse entry? i.e

nslookup example.com resolves to 1.2.3.4
nslookup 1.2.3.4 should resolves to example.com

I suspect that to be a reason. Ask your provider to create a reverse entry (PTR entry) for the host from where you are sending the emails. For further improvement you might want to add a spf record.

Answer (score 2):

You have no mx record.  Major flag there. You want them to accept your mail and yet you have no MX to receive mail? That screams spam to them.
You have no SPF record. Take a minute, add one.
You have no DKIM.

In short, you do nothing to make yourselves look legit.

Answer (score 0):

Also check whether your HELO name on the system is sanely configured. Should exactly match what the reverse DNS for its IP returns, anything else is another major red flag.